# What is suitable location for creating sqlite file?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

Actually, My app got rejected from app store because i am storing about 9 MB data in document directory.

What is better and suitable location store image cache and to create sqlite database file?

Comment: probably it may be reject for some other reason

Comment: Yeah, Its not rejected due to sqlite file but i am worried because got rejected due to invalid data storage.

Answer (score 1):

The *image **cache*** has to go into the **cache** directory. A cache should not be included in a backup because you can recreate those images easily.

If the sqlite file stores user data you should put it into the document directory. It has to be included in device backups because you can't recreate it and the user would lose all his data when he restores his device from a backup.

If the sqlite file is downloaded from the web and it is never changed by the user put it into the cache directory too. On iOS 5.0.1 and later you could put that file into the documents directory and set the ["Do not backup"-Attribute](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html). However, on device with iOS 5.0 or earlier you HAVE to put that file in the caches directory.

```
NSString *cacheDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
```

Comment: Thank you for actually telling me the path of this directory. Every page in the internet just tells me put it in cache directory, without bothering to tell me where exactly it is. So thank you, you are very considerate!

Answer (score 1):

The concern area is the iOS 5.0, which supports iCloud, but does not recognizes “do not backup” attribute. In this case, all the data of the app inside documents directory is likely to get backed up to iCloud. For the iOS versions below 5.x:

```
the iCloud backup is not valid.
the "do not back up" flag is not relevent. It would not produce any warnings during compilation.
```

Hence the data can be kept in the documents directory, with "do not back up" flag appropiately added to the contents (files/folders), for all the versions. The problem is for the version 5.0 only.

Answer (score -1):

if you have lot of image in Your application.then sotre images in any image store site and use link of image. its better for You.