# iOS File Storage: Solution for Not Backing Up

Tags: ios, file, backup, storage, icloud

Like many developers, my iOS app was just rejected for having downloadable content that was being backed up to iCloud. I've searched for a clear answer to this question but have not been able to get one.

Apple says that you should implement a 'do not backup' attribute to your files, however, they also state (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html):

The new "do not back up" attribute will only be used by iOS 5.0.1 or later. On iOS 5.0 and earlier, applications will need to store their data in /Library/Caches to avoid having it backed up. Since this attribute is ignored on older systems, you will need to insure your app complies with the iOS Data Storage Guidelines on all versions of iOS that your application supports.

My app supports iOS 4.0 and later. Does this mean if I want to maintain support for iOS 4.0-5.0, I have no choice but to put all my content into the Caches folder? Or, can I just add the 'do not backup' attribute and keep the files in /Documents? If I have to keep the content in the Caches folder, can I prevent these files from being purged in low storage situations? Finally, are there any developers who have put files in the Caches folder and know how often they do get purged?

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I added the do not backup flag but ended up making it such that the entire documents folder is not backed up. Is this still acceptable of the user is not generating any other files?

Answer (score 1):

The concern area is the iOS 5.0, which supports iCloud, but does not recognizes “do not backup” attribute. In this case, all the data of the app inside documents directory is likely to get backed up to iCloud. For the iOS versions below 5.x:

- the iCloud backup is not valid.
- the "do not back up" flag is not relevent. It would not produce any warnings during compilation.

Hence the data can be kept in the documents directory, with "do not back up" flag appropiately added to the contents (files/folders), for all the versions. The problem is for the version 5.0 only.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can find similar question like this :

[What is suitable location for creating sqlite file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784288/what-is-suitable-location-for-creating-sqlite-file)

and as per my thinking it is better to store files in library with new directory rather than document directory..

Comment: Caches directory it's deleted all time...if you want to storage file permanently without move it in iCloud you must save it in Documents and flag it as do not backup. There is no way. This is the best practice https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html

Comment: Will my app still be approved if I support earlier versions of iOS or should I just raise the minimum to 5.0.1?

Answer (score 0):

No it's wrong that tou say. I've solved your same problem in that way. I saved my database and directory images in directory Documents/.. flagons those As do not backup as suggest by Apple. In that way for devices that are updated to 5.x or more that files are not backup to iCloud; for others there are no changes because there are no support to iCloud.

This is a best practice because files that are not concerning user we do not backup in iCloud. All other files that you don't want to redownload must be saved in Documents flagging it as do not backup. If you save it in Caches folder those are deleted in a short time when you close the app and must be redownloded when you open it again.

Comment: iOS 5.0.0 supports iCloud so will the app still be approved if I support earlier versions?

Comment: For sure, I support from 4.0 as you.

Comment: For iOS minus than 5 don't change nothing because those files are not storage in iCloud...than you can give their support.

Comment: Yes, I understand that theres nothing to worry about for iOS 4.x but its 5.0.0 thats causing me confusion.

Comment: 5.x support iCloud and do not backup...less no changes!